# Using histcountsmex instead of histcounts

Tags: performance, matlab, mex, data-analysis, binning

I'm trying to optimize my MATLAB code. My code requires the use of `histcounts` function over a million vectors in a for-loop. What I want to do is to directly use `histcountsmex` instead of `histcounts`. Can anyone suggest how to do that?
This is my function:

```
function th = sndmode( mh )
    % this function will find the threshold 
    % the mode of the function that is not zero
    [count, centers]=histcounts(mh,sort((mh))); % find the most repeated elements
    [~, indxs]=sort(count,'descend'); % sort the result
    centers=centers(indxs);
    if centers(1)==0 % determine the first nonzero mode
         th=centers(2);
    else
         th=centers(1);
    end
end
```

Now when I run profiler it says that 34 seconds is spent on the 'histcounts' function but 14 seconds is spent on 'histcountsmex'.

Comment: How many of these vectors can you fit in memory at once?

Comment: The length of each vector is between 10 to 50 thousand samples.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question... Also, why are you convinced that the bottleneck is `histcounts`? Please show us some code, including what you already tried regarding `histcountsmex`.

Comment: @AboozarRoosta To build on Dev-iL's question, have you used any timing analysis functions (like `profile`) to see that `histcounts` is the reason why your code is slow?

Comment: @rayryeng Yes. Look at my explanation after the code.

Answer (score 0):

add histcountsmex.p to your current work path. 
It is located in C:\ProgramFiles\MATLAB\R2017b\toolbox\matlab\datafun\private\histcountsmex.p